# Connection timeout HTTP put request

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, redis, debian

I've come across a really nice project on GitHub and wanted to give it a shot but it isn't exactly working as it should: https://github.com/jack3898/discord-youtube-bot-2

It's a Discord music bot which supports YouTube, it is using docker, docker-compose and redis and all those 3 things were new to me when I first found it a few days ago.

The bot works like a charm while using docker and docker-compose on Windows but problem comes when I try to run it on my Debian 11 server.

```
Creating redis ... done
Creating bot   ... done
Attaching to redis, bot
redis    | 1:C 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.879 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis    | 1:C 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.879 # Redis version=6.2.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis    | 1:C 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.880 # Configuration loaded
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.881 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.884 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.884 # Server initialized
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.884 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.886 * <ReJSON> version: 20006 git sha: db3329c branch: heads/v2.0.6
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.886 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V1 API
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.895 * <ReJSON> Enabled diskless replication
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.895 * <ReJSON> Created new data type 'ReJSON-RL'
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.896 * Module 'ReJSON' loaded from /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.899 * <search> Redis version found by RedisSearch : 6.2.5 - oss
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.899 * <search> RediSearch version 2.2.5 (Git=v1.99.5-386-g93a916c4)
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.899 * <search> Low level api version 1 initialized successfully
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.900 * <search> concurrent writes: OFF, gc: ON, prefix min length: 2, prefix max expansions: 200, query timeout (ms): 500, timeout policy: return, cursor read size: 1000, cursor max idle (ms): 300000, max doctable size: 1000000, max number of search results:  1000000, search pool size: 20, index pool size: 8,
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.905 * <search> Initialized thread pool!
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.905 * <search> Acquired RedisJSON_V1 API
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.906 * <search> Enabled diskless replication
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.906 * Module 'search' loaded from /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so
redis    | 1:M 17 Jan 2022 19:40:56.907 * Ready to accept connections
bot      |
bot      | > discord-youtube-bot-2@1.0.0 bot
bot      | > cross-env NODE_ENV=production ts-node src/index.ts -p tsconfig.builds.json
bot      |
bot      | Environment: production
bot      | Redis host: redis
bot      | Bot logged in as MusicBOT!
bot      | Started refreshing application slash commands.
bot      | 19 unique commands have been found on the file system.
bot      | /home/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:163
bot      |             socket.setTimeout(__classPrivateFieldGet(this, _RedisSocket_options, "f").connectTimeout, () => socket.destroy(new errors_1.ConnectionTimeoutError()));
bot      |                                                                                                                            ^
bot      | ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout
bot      |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:163:124)
bot      |     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
bot      |     at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
bot      |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
bot      |     at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:501:8)
bot      |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
bot      |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

As you can see it basically crashes with error "Connection timeout". After some quick digging through code I've found that it crashes on HTTP request. (Second line of code from the bottom)

```
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { config, globals } from 'bot-config';
import { Routes } from 'discord-api-types/v9';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

/**
 * This function registers all slash commands to the Discord API.
 * It also stores all command classes in the globals object to be used later.
 */
export async function registerCommands() {
    const { discordToken, clientId, devGuildId } = config;
    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(discordToken as string);

    console.log('Started refreshing application slash commands.');

    // Create an endpoint to the Discord API that has the relevant Bot ID.
    // If not in production, the development Guild ID is added to speed up the command registration process.
    const route =
        config.environment === 'production'
            ? Routes.applicationCommands(clientId as string)
            : Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId as string, devGuildId as string);

    // This section simply finds all command classes.
    const commandModulePath = path.resolve('src', 'commands', 'modules');
    const commandModuleResolvingEntries = fs.readdirSync(commandModulePath).map(async moduleName => {
        const module = await import(`${commandModulePath}/${moduleName}`);
        return [moduleName, module];
    });

    const commandModules = await Promise.all(commandModuleResolvingEntries);

    // Register all commands to the Discord API and add the commands to the globals commandModules Map() instance.
    const slashCommandRegistrations = commandModules.map(module => {
        const commandName = module[0].split('.')[0].toLowerCase(); // Remove the '.ts' at the end and force lowercase.
        const commandClass = module[1].default;
        globals.commandModules.set(commandName, commandClass);
        return new commandClass().register().toJSON();
    });

    console.log(`${globals.commandModules.size} unique commands have been found on the file system.`);

    // Send a HTTP PUT request to the Discord API to register all slash commands.
    await rest.put(route, { body: slashCommandRegistrations });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application slash commands.');
}
```

I'm really unable to find out, what is causing a problem like that. It is probably just some rookie thing which I'm unable to see.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks vparys for submitting this question!! It's the bot author here. I would like to add some details to the problem.

- I think it's to do with hostname resolution on the private network.

- I think it could be localised to *NIX OS's, but I have not tried it on any other OSs yet.

- Bit of me thinks it might be a bug. Not sure.

Comment: You will also find the connection string is this: `static client = createClient({ url: \`redis://${config.redisHost}:${config.redisPort}\` });`. If you visit the repo, you can find it in src/classes/modules/Cache.ts

Answer (score 0):

All solved!

The problem has to do with declaring multiple Redis clients.

Two can be found between `Cache.ts` and `QueueManager.ts`. Creating one Redis client is all that is needed, and will remove the timeout issue.

A bit of bad practice on my part I think! But I learned something new.